# Celery: Get children of a group

Tags: python, celery

How to get the individual states of the items in a celery group?

I tried this:

```
job = group([my_task.s(item) for item in items])
job.apply_async(task_id=my_id))

result = AsyncResult(id=my_id)
assert 0, (result.state, result.children)
```

> ('PENDING', None)

But `result.children` is always `None`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the result of a group a different object is needed - the `celery.result.GroupResult`. Both AsyncResult that you tried to use, and GroupResult are ResultBase subtypes (although GroupResult is a subclass of ResultSet, which is a subclass of ResultBase, just like AsyncResult) so they behave quite similar. Once you have GroupResult object you can use its `results` member to iterate AsyncResult objects and check their states.

Comment: I am not sure why this would work - `GroupResult(id=job.id).results` also returns `None`?